# Validation formula for rich text field

Tags: validation, formula, lotus, richtext

I have this code to validate my rich texts if the user has not set a value.

```
@If(Attachment1= "" ; @Do(@Prompt([Ok]; "Validation Error"; "Cannot leave blank Attachments."); @Return("")); "");

@If(Attachment2= "" ; @Do(@Prompt([Ok]; "Validation Error"; "Cannot leave blank Attachments."); @Return("")); "");
```

The problem is, even though the rich text has a value, it keeps on prompting that
it is blank.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can not validate rich text fields in the same way as you validate other fields.

This article on DeveloperWorks provides three methods to do it:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/rich-text-field-notes/index.html

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried doing querysave. But the thing is I need to validate it before saving the document. I also tried @attachments but i figured out that it wasn't usefull if you have more than one rich text field.

Comment: Did you try any of the Lotusscript methods mentioned in the article? They all use the NotesUIDocument class which represents the frontend document and therefore make it possible to validate an unsaved document.

Comment: I've tried all three of them. I have a submit button which will send email and save the document. What happens, if I click the submit it will first send an email then the --- Sub Querysave(Source As Notesuidocument, Continue As Variant)
            If ( Source.FieldGetText( "rtfield" ) = "" ) Then
  Messagebox( "Please enter some text." )
  Call Source.GotoField( "rtfield" )
  Continue = False
 End If
End Sub --- will prompt "Please enter some text". Then it will ask if I would like to save the document. I really wanted to validate it first before sending an email and saving the document.

Comment: Then add the code to the submit button instead. You need to add "Dim uidoc as Notesuidocument" and then use uidoc instead of Source in the code in the button

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your effort helping me. I can't add the code to submit button, because my submit button is consist of several formula including the sending emails and saving the document. How I wish that formula can combine to lotusscript.

Comment: Can you save before sending the email in order to trigger the querySave event?

Comment: That's what I really think is best solution so that it will validate, but the flow of the application I'm making is that it must validate it first.

Comment: Go ahead and convert your button to Lotusscript so that you can validate the rich text field as part of the flow.